# I can not find 74HCT374 model on LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

I'm trying to find a 74HCT374 LTSpice model. Where can I find it?

Comment: Probably going to have to either find one from TI (who have models for a lot of their parts), or make your own.

Comment: There's a model for that at the groups.io web site for LTspice. I forget who made it. But once the ZIP is installed you will have a ZZZ folder available to you. Then it is sym/ZZZ/Logic/74HCT/74hct374. It's all there. I can't say it simulates well or fast. Maybe so. I've not tried it. But it is there.

Comment: What jonk said. The library is from (Alex) Bordodynov  (Александр Бордодынов) and you should download and install it. Follow the installation instructions carefully, there are variations depending on version and/or OS.

Comment: I'm search this page  ''https://groups.io/g/LTspice'' and click at all_files_z_groups.io.htm
But i do not have anything download it carry me to same page

Answer (score 2):

Try the 74HCT374 from my collection:
https://github.com/HenniePeters/LTSpice/tree/master/_PERSONAL/74HCT